# X-axis values on grouped bar chart

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts, swift3

I have created group bar using `iOS Charts` library but unable to set X-axis values properly in swift3. 
So please help.

I add data like this

```
for i in 0 < data.count {
    let dataEntryForHours1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(value))
    let dataEntryForHours2 = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(value))
}
```

but still getting random double values on X-Axis like `-0.5,0.3, 0.6` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an interval from 0 to data.count.

```
for i in 0..<data.count {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I am assigning the same i.e. (value of i ```BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(value))```)

Comment: Hi Pritam, Can you share some more code (especially the values you have in data ) ?